# What is "Priority" and "Resource" in XMPP?

Tags: protocol, xmpp, jabber

I don´t know if those are the names in english, but it spanish is "Prioridad" and "Recurso". I see this when I want to configure an XMPP client. In "Priority" I see that I have to put a number, and I suppose (I´m not sure) that depending on the number the messages will get on the account with the highest number, or is it the other way around?
And in "Resource" I don´t have a theory, for example when I configure my Jabber account on Thunderbird, by default the resource is "Thunderbird", and when it is on ChatSecure, the resource is "ChatSecure-12345678"[1]
I´ve not found any documentation about this in the Web. Where can I read about this?

[1] The "12345678" is a random set of numbers and letters, which are always 8, and they are different of the other accounts (this only in happens in [ChatSecure](https://chatsecure.org/))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Priority and Resource are relevant when you are online with multiple clients (with the same JID).

Let’s say your JID is `alice@example.net` and you are online with two clients:

- **Client 1**
  Priority: `5`
  Resource: `home`
- **Client 2**
  Priority: `7`
  Resource: `mobile`

If someone sends a message to `alice@example.net/home`,
you will receive it on Client 1.

If someone sends a message to `alice@example.net/mobile`,
you will receive it on Client 2.

If someone sends a message to `alice@example.net`,
you will receive it on Client 2, because it has the higher priority.

**tl;dr:** The Resource allows the sender to identify/target specific clients, and the Priority decides which client will be used in case the sender doesn’t target a specific Resource.

---

The Priority can go from `-128` to `127`. If you set a negative Priority (e.g., `-1`), this client will never receive a message unless the sender explicitly sends it to that’s client Resource. If the clients have the same positive Priority, all of them should get the message.

Some clients append random strings to the Resource (probably what ChatSecure does) to make the full JID unpredictable, which [can be relevant for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14601763/1591669).

Comment: How to [set XMPP priority of the jabber client in pidgin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568766/4319).